# Blender weight painting is offsetting mesh when adding automatic weights

Tags: weight-painting

In the attached images, I have a mesh added with automatic weights to a model. When I paint the forearm to deform with the forearm bone, the mesh begins to offset. When it's not painted, it lines with with the armature. Any idea why this is happening? I checked to see if any other bones are effecting that part of the mesh and they aren't. This only happens on the forearm, the rest of the mesh deforms fine with the rest of the body when weight painted. I also tried adjust the scale of the shirt mesh and the model.[image][image]

Comment: My guess is that you have the armature in a posed state. One possible cause is that you mixed up Edit mode and Pose mode when modelling the armature. Does this still happen if you go to the armature object > Pose mode > A to select all > Alt + R to reset rotation?